# How to create a (or modify an existing) pgm 5 file in C?

Tags: c, pgm

For example say I want to create a 100x100 pgm file, how do I proceed? It's different than creating and modifying a text file as I'll have to open it as binary.

Comment: What sort of code/approaches have you already tried?

Comment: To open as binary just use `fopen(filename, "wb")`.